# Help with IQueryables and lazyLoading in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading, repository-pattern

Say i want to add pagination support.
My app is separated in Web, Services and repositories.

The Controller only speaks to the Service and the Service gets Data and does business logic.

Say i want pagination support.. I have this method in my ContributorService

```
public IQueryable<Contributor> GetContributors(int page, int pageSize)
        {
            return _repository.GetAll().OrderBy(c=>c.ACC_CREATEDATE).Skip((page)*pageSize).Take(pageSize);//solo temporalmente
        }
```

is that ok?? or should the OrderBy, Skip, Take be done in the repository?

which currently only does this

```
public IQueryable<Contributor> GetAll()
        {
            return db.Contributors;
        }
```

Comment: Either way it makes no difference since the query is executed only when  ".ToList()" is called on IQueryable or the first element in the colleciton is accessed. Can be confirmed through LinqToSqlProfiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the query to the business object ( I think you dont have one, do you), there you may have a base version of it, and another one for the paged data. And would expect to service to execute that query by calling the ToList, I find it dangerous to return a query object to the controller.

Your repository might have a GetPartial Method, with the sort, from, to, and a filter params. If you have a generic service, you might also implement this in that generic service.

```
public List<Contributor> GetPartial<TSortBy>(Expression<Func<Contributor, TSortBy>> sortByExpr, Expression<Func<Contributor, bool>> filterExpr, int pageNo, int pageSize)
        {
            var query = db.Contributors;
            if (filterExpr != null)
                   query.Where(filterExpr);
query.orderBy(sortByExpr).Skip (...).Take(...).ToList();

        }
```

if you have a Repository class, you can add this method.
By the way, I am using Dynamic LINQ, which makes it easier to pass order by expression as plain text (just like sql)